# how does grafana dashboard show jenkins as down when the jenkins server is stopped rather than just saying "no data available"

Tags: jenkins, prometheus, grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-api

**Background:** I have a linux server where I configured my jenkins and installed the prometheus plugin to scrape the jenkins instance metrics. I am using grafana dashboard to visualize and monitor the jenkins server. In grafana I have used the grafana's pre-configured jenkins dashboard for jenkins monitoring and prometheus datasource to import the metrics to Grafana.

```
> Jenkins url - https://<ipaddr>:8080/test
> Prometheus scrape jenkins metrics url: https://<ipaddr>:8080/test/prometheus
```

**Problem statement:** Whenever I stop the jenkins process on my jenkins server then the grafana dashboard show as "**no data available**" or whenever there is some issue with prometheus plugin then also it shows "**no data available**". I know this is happening because prometheus is unable to scrape the metrics since the jenkins server itself is down which results in blank data passed to grafana from prometheus datasource. I just wanted to know is there any way where I could display the specific metrics in grafana which says jenkins down when jenkins process is stopped. Grafana should say the exact error at jenkins instead of just saying "**no data available**". Is there any custom grafana way to display the error message atleast when there is a problem with jenkins server itself.